# Thunderbird Email ver 102.02 change email properties : Location. Recover previous emails

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I have an issue that occurred since last upgrade to version 102.02. One of my accounts is no longer able to access the mail server and none of my emails show up.

I noticed that in the location property of account properties window:
imap://myemailName%40provider.net@imap.mail.provider.com/INBOX
This really should be
imap://myemailName%40provider.net@imap.provider.net/INBOX

I read online to create a new account - but this means I delete this current account setup and where are all of my stored emails / archived emails etc.. for this account ??
What do I need to do to fix this issue and be able to recover my emails and saved folders etc ..??

Answer (score 0):

All of your emails are stored/archived *on the IMAP server itself,* not in Thunderbird.

To change your IMAP server's address, go to Thunderbird main menu → "Account Settings".